# how to use db.query() when i have many conditions in where clause?? #android

Tags: android, sqlite

i have a table with columns ID,SUBJECT,BRANCH

i have select the rows which satisfies the follwing conditions

```
id=rollno  
branch=cse  
subject=any subject  




db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
        ID,SUBJECT,BRANCH}, 
        where clause, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null);
```

how to write where clause here to satisfy my conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add Where clauses with  " **AND** ".. Pretty simple.. Each condition is seperated by the same..

here is an example

```
String addrWhere = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID+" = ? AND "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+" = ?"; //this is where clause and below is corresponding selection args..  
String[] addrWhereParams = new String[]{data.getContac_ID(), 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};
```

Comment: public Cursor getAllRows(int roll,int att)  
    {    
  
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
      KEY_ROLLNO,KEY_ATTENDANCE}, 
            KEY_ROLLNO + "=" + roll+"AND"+KEY_ATTENDANCE +"="+ att, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
     } i wrote like this...i am not getting output..is there any mistake

Comment: You missed a space and **?** after **=**.. follow my post.. thats working code.. Even space is important..

Comment: i am not using selection args...i like give values there itself...so i guess no need to use ?

Comment: in your where statemnt,,... **KEY_ROLLNO + " = " + roll+" AND "+KEY_ATTENDANCE + " = "+ att** paste this...

Comment: @kumar .. post a raw querry if you are comfortale with that.. are else  go thro a tutorial first..

Answer (score 3):

You can use db.rawQuery methos also

```
Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("select * from <table_name> where id='1' and 
branch='" + branchName + "' and subject='" + subjectName+ "'");
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply...i have one more...actually i am passing  branch name and subject name as arguments to the function...how can use i use that arguments in raw select statement here ??